# Regex Matching Certain Lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to clean some Data that I get from a command.
The issue is the data is repeated for different cases and spread on multiple lines.
I added the Data at the end of the question.

I am trying to Grab the `Domain|Private|Public` with their state `ON|OFF`

an example output would be this

```
Domain  OFF
Private ON
Public  OFF
```

because of the multiple lines and my limited knowledge of Regex, I can only match one line.
Can someone please help me with this regex.

Data Sample:

```
Domain Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 OFF
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Enable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096


Private Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 OFF
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Enable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096


Public Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 OFF
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Enable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096

Ok.
```

Comment: What language do you use? What have you tried?

Comment: What application are you using? This looks like it should be pretty simple using `awk`.

Comment: Powershell regex -math command. Currently testing out in regexpal.com also [\n\r].*State\s*([^\n\r]*) is my latest code

Comment: Is `state` always the first item of the list?

Comment: @tobias_k, maybe, will depend on the OS so I am not positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my question:

```
%{$_.Replace(' Profile Settings: ', '')} | 
            where {$_ -match '(Domain|Public|Private|State)'} |
            %{$_ -Replace('State *','')}
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 3):

```
(Domain|Public|Private).*?^State\s+(ON|OFF)
```

You will need to enable `dotall` and `multiline` flags - how to do this depends on your specific environment.

The regexp in order first recognizes and stores the scope keyword, then skips a non-greedy amount of random characters until the `State` string is encountered at the start of a line (due to the `^` character), and then an arbitrary number of whitespace characters are allowed before encountering either `ON` or `OFF`. Both the scope and the state are returned as actual matches. The use of `.*?` in the middle ensures that the match also works if `State` isn't on the first line.

[Sample here](http://regexr.com?382tn).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a PCRE compliant regex, this should do it:

```
/(Domain|Public|Private)\s+.*?State\s+(ON|OFF)/gs
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pG3iI6

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = <filename to search>
select-string -Pattern 'Domain|Private|Public Profile Settings' -Path $file -Context 0,2 | 
foreach {[PSCustomObject]@{
                        Type = $_.line.split()[0]
                        Setting = $_.Context.PostContext[1].split()[-1]
                      }
    } | ft -AutoSize
```

That uses the -Context parameter of Select-String to grab the next 2 lines after the Profile string, and parse the setting from the PostContext.  You may want to replace the splits with -replace, depending on your data.

Comment: Getting error: the parameter Path is empty even though the Write-Host shows its content

Comment: It works for me, using a file with your test data copied to it (e.g. $file = 'c:\testfiles\file1.txt')